# Second nameserver in /etc/resolv.conf not picked up by wget

Tags: domain-name-system, resolv.conf

My `resolv.conf` looks like this:

```
; generated by /sbin/dhclient-script
search mcdc
nameserver 10.0.4.48
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

If I do `nslookup www.google.com` it works

```
nslookup www.google.com
;; Got SERVFAIL reply from 10.0.4.48, trying next server
Server:     8.8.8.8
Address:    8.8.8.8#53

Non-authoritative answer:
www.google.com  canonical name = www.l.google.com.
```

but when I curl [www.google.com](http://www.google.com), it cannot resolve the host.

I tried running curl under strace, and found curl was only using the first nameserver in `resolv.conf`, not the second. If I switch the two nameserver lines around, [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) resolves, but internal DNS names do not, so that's not a good workaround.

How can I fix `resolv.conf` to use both nameservers?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The default behavior for resolv.conf and the resolver is to try the servers in the order listed. The resolver will only try the next nameserver if the first nameserver times out. The [resolv.conf manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/5/resolv.conf) says:

> nameserver Name server IP address
>
> Internet address (in dot notation) of a name server that the resolver
>   should query.  Up to  MAXNS  (currently  3,  see  )  name
>   servers  may  be  listed,  one per keyword.  **If there are multiple
>   servers, the resolver library queries them in the order listed.**

And:

> (The algorithm used is to try a name server, and  if  the  query times out, try the next, until out of name servers, then repeat trying all the name servers until a maximum number of retries are made.)

Also see the [resolver(5)](http://linux.die.net/man/5/resolver) manual page for more information.

You can alter the resolver's behavior using `rotate`, which will query the Nameservers in a round-robin order:

> rotate sets RES_ROTATE in _res.options, which causes round robin
>   selection of nameservers from among those listed. This has the effect
>   of spreading the query load among all listed servers, rather than
>   having all clients try the first listed server first every time.

However, nslookup will use the second nameserver if it receives a `SERVFAIL` from the first nameserver. From the [nslookup manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/1/nslookup):

> [no]fail
>      Try the next nameserver if a nameserver responds with SERVFAIL or a referral (nofail) or terminate query (fail) on such a response.
>
> (Default = nofail)

Answer (score 12):

yes you could use "rotate" and timeout setting to improve DNS lookups,
below is the example,

Ex:

```
[root@centos-xxxxxx ~]# cat /etc/resolv.conf
options rotate
options timeout:1
search xyz.abc.local
nameserver 192.168.56.3
nameserver 10.0.2.4
```

Comment: For me, this sort of works, but not reliably. It basically relies on the client retrying until it gets the right name server, which sometimes works, sometimes doesn't.

Answer (score 8):

So to make it work as expected install dnsmasq or other lightweight DNS repeater (or a full blown DNS server). See [Comparison of DNS server software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_DNS_server_software).

For dnsmasq configuration is as simple as:

```
server=10.0.4.48
server=8.8.8.8
```

You can also specify which DNS should be used for which domain . E.g.:

```
server=/mcdc/10.0.4.48
server=8.8.8.8
```

This will make dnsmasq look for `*.mcdc` in `10.0.4.48` DNS server and any other in `8.8.8.8`.

In `/etc/resolv.conf` you just use your local DNS:

```
nameserver 127.0.0.1
```

For more details on dnsmasq setup see my answer here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/55090/change-default-dns-on-openvpn-connect/545591#545591.

Answer (score 1):

Is 10.0.4.48 a recursive dns server aka resolver?

Or is it only an authoritative server for your internal zones?

You should set up an internal resolver that might also be holding your authoritative data.

Answer (score 1):

adding the below command in starting of resolv conf worked in ubuntu 18.04 LTS

```
options rotate
```

Answer (score -3):

If you can, I would configure it in this fashion.

`search mcdc
nameserver 127.0.0.1
nameserver 8.8.8.8`

Comment: Which part of the question indicates they run a DNS server on their machine, or want to?

Comment: [***WHY*** do you think querying localhost will improve their situation?](http://blog.serverfault.com/2011/06/09/press-the-green-button-twice/)

Comment: Blake: Note that 127.0.0.1 is typically only used for systems which have a name server caching daemon on the local host. See http://tldp.org/HOWTO/DNS-HOWTO-3.html