# Resolv Conf Multiple DNS Servers with specific domains

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, openvpn, linux-networking, resolv.conf

I need the ability to have specific dns servers for multiple networks, and i would like to know how to properly update my `/etc/resolv.conf`:

lets say I have a major vpn, that I route all my trafiic and DNS queries through it. 
But know I have another VPN that gives me specific accesss to a network, that VPN also as a DNS server, but it only serves a specific domain lets say: ´mydomain.local´

I have a constructed the following resolv.conf:

```
nameserver 10.8.0.1
search mydomain.local
nameserver 10.250.0.2
```

But the DNS queries will go on to the first domain server no matter what, changing order does not matter.

Can anyone give me any suggestion?

Answer (score 21):

Impossible to achieve using `/etc/resolv.conf` only.

I'd say the easiest thing is to install `dnsmasq` (a caching DNS client), make it the sole resolver by putting `nameserver 127.0.0.1` into `/etc/resolv.conf` and then modify `dnsmasq` configuration:

- uncomment `no-dhcp-interface=` to disable `dnsmasq`'s DHCP server facilities;
- add a single generic record: `server=10.8.0.1`;
- add specific record: `server=/mydomain.local/10.250.0.2` to all requests for hosts in `mydomail.local` go to that server.

Answer (score 4):

Actually this can be done if you are using dnsmasq.

At the bottom of your /etc/dnsmasq.conf file you can add lines like this:

```
server=/domain.net/172.166.7.23
server=/domain.com/142.124.17.12
```

I haven't tested it on more than my machine, but it works for me.

My requirement was because my VPN client was not using the correct nameservers when connected to a workplace to route internal addresses.  This fixed it to use internal DNS servers for specific domains.

Answer (score 2):

This could be difficult to achieve, using plain `/etc/resolv.conf` only, imho. Would it be a problem, to install a local resolver? If not - the following plan might be applicable:

1. Install a cache-only DNS from your distro repository. The default configuration should work and usually you have `127.0.0.1` as a listening address only.
2. Backup your existing `/etc/resolv.conf` and create a new one, containing barely `nameserver 127.0.0.1`. Test that your local DNS works correctly, resolving Internet names.
3. Put the following in the `named.conf`:

`zone "mydomain.local" {
    type forward;
    forward only;
    forwarders { Your-VPN-DNS-IP; };
};`

4. Test it again, both Internet and VPN resolution. If successful, you could add a `search` line to `/etc/resolv.conf`.

HTH-RB

Answer (score 1):

this has been answered elsewhere i SO.

https://serverfault.com/a/832437/118396

Short answer is yes you can achieve this with resolv.conf options. Even though not with per-domain dns assignment, but rather with rotation across nameservers.

```
[root@centos-xxxxxx ~]# cat /etc/resolv.conf
options rotate
options timeout:1
search xyz.abc.local
nameserver 192.168.56.3
nameserver 10.0.2.4
```